# vba Auto rebuild of Pivot Table DataField collapse

Tags: vba, excel

I have been given the task to maintain a report with multiple pivot tables that summarize Data Source sheets that get updated weekly.

The Data Sources have multiple column headers that change (e.g. Oct, Nov, Dec & 9/14, 9/21, 9/28).  Thus, every time the pivot tables are refreshed, PivotFields get dropped and need to be re-added manually … to me a royal pain!  Anyway, I have been trying to automate the “rebuild” of these pivot tables.    I have code that will add a positioned PivotField, however the caption’s title has to be entered.  I am looking for a way to pass the text in the data source column to the code that updates the pivot.  I posted the version that works when typed in, and the version that does not work where I am trying to pass the text from the data source.  I believe I am close, but I just cannot figure out why this approach is not working.  Any help or ideas will be much appreciated.

Code that works:

```
Sub pivottable1()

   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Sep Actual Hrs thru 9/25")
      .Orientation = xlDataField
      .Position = 2
   End With

End Sub
```

My attempt to retrieve the caption text from the data source (that does not currently work):

```
Sub PivotFieldAdd()

Dim pf As PivotField

Worksheets("Actual Data").Select   'name of the data source
'pf = Range("I3").Value

    'With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("pf")    'this doesn't work either.
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields = Range("I3").Value
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 2
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure what are you trying to achieve here ? is `"Worksheets("Actual Data")` the SourceData of your PivotTable ? If it is, once you refresh the PivotTable, all data (and headers) should be refreshed according to changes to the source data

Comment: Yes, "Worksheets("Actual Data") is the SourceData.  The problem I am try to solve for is that some of the column headers in the SourceData change (weekly). So, when you go to refresh that PivotField drops.  So I am looking for a way to look up the new column header name, and add a PivotField back into the Pivot with that name as the caption.  Without having to update multiple PivotTables manually.

Comment: the `PivotField` ? it should be the`PivotItems`, no ? If not, then either your SourceData is not constrcuted correctly, or yout PivotTable

Comment: Yes, Pivot Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLVED) Purpose: rebuilds pivot when data source column header changes.

```
Sub WklyPivotFieldAdd()
'Purpose: rebuilds pivot when data source column header changes.
Dim pf1 As String
Dim pf2 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'Stops screen flicker, increases speed.

pf1 = Worksheets("Actual Data").[I3] 'Location of the data source column header that changes
pf2 = Worksheets("Actual Data").[J3] 'Location of the data source column header that changes

'Sets the PivotField name to the source column name for second column in DataField
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields(pf1)
        .Orientation = xlDataField              'Places the new column in the DataField area
        .Position = 2                           'Second column over
   End With

   'Sets the PivotField name to the source column name for Fifth column in DataField
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields(pf2)
        .Orientation = xlDataField              'Places the new column in the DataField area
        .Position = 5                           'Fifth column over
   End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True       'Starts automatic screen updating

End Sub
```